# How do i make an object stop moving if it has collided with a wall in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am making a mini-game that involves movement. I created an object that moves according to the controls, but how do i make it not move if it collides with a wall?

```
#Imports
import pygame, sys


#Functions




#General Set Up
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Main Window

swid = 1280        
shgt = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((swid, shgt))
pygame.display.set_caption("Raid: The Game || Movement Test")


#Game Rectangles

player = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 30, 30)
wall = pygame.Rect(140, 80, 1000, 20)
window = pygame.Rect(300, 400, 220, 20)
door = pygame.Rect(500, 500, 120, 18)

bgcol = (0,0,0)
playercol = (200,0,0)
wallcol = pygame.Color("grey12")
doorcol = pygame.Color("blue")
windowcol = (100,100,100)

xwalkspeed = 0
ywalkspeed = 0


while True:
    #Handling Input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ywalkspeed += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ywalkspeed -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xwalkspeed -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xwalkspeed += 10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ywalkspeed -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ywalkspeed += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xwalkspeed += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xwalkspeed -= 10
    
    
    
    player.x += xwalkspeed
    player.y += ywalkspeed

    distancebetween = 0

    if player.colliderect(wall):
        ywalkspeed = 0
        xwalkspeed= 0
                       

    if player.top <= 0:
        player.top = 0
    
    if player.bottom >= shgt:
        player.bottom = shgt

    if player.left <= 0:
        player.left = 0

    if player.right >= swid:
        player.right = swid


    
    #Visuals
    screen.fill(bgcol)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, playercol, player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, wallcol, wall)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, doorcol, door)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, windowcol, window)


    #Updating the Window
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Whenever my Object collides upon a wall, it starts moving the opposite way until it is no longer seen in the screen.

I Found the Reason why it kept moving the opposite way when it collides the wall. It is because if I move towards the wall, my `ywalkspeed = 10` and when I collided with the wall, it becomes `0`, then if I started to let go of the movement key, the ywalkspeed becomes `ywalkspeed = -10`. I currently don't know a way how to fix this as I am just a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original player rectangle with [`copy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.copy). Move the player. If a collision is detected, restore the player rectangle:

```py
copy_of_player_rect = player.copy()

# move player
# [...]

if player.colliderect(wall):
    player = copy_of_player_rect
```

Comment: I've done Rabbid76's suggestion. It did work, but as soon as it collides with the wall, it closes and says "pygame.Rect" object is not Callable.

Comment: Good Point. But apparently, the code is too long, maybe i'll edit it later

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for the distance between the wall and the player and when the distance according to axis positions reaches zero, just do

```
xwalkspeed = 0
ywalkspeed = 0
```

To measure the distance and smooth realistic movement, you can also use equations of motion from Physics.